# PHP + cURL, parsing header data

Tags: php, json, curl, vimeo

Summary:
I am using PHP/cURL to get some JSON data from Vimeo.

This has been working fine, (albeit their odd 'rate limit' requirements), using the following:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $json_url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("authorization: Bearer ".$access_token)
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$response_info = curl_getinfo($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Which works fine when I covert to JSON and use the data output like so:

```
$vimeoJSON = json_decode($response, true);

echo '<h2 class="title">'.$vimeoJSON['name'] . '</h2>';
```

However, Vimeo sends back some needed data (current rate-limit and remaining limit..etc) in the HEADER RESPONSE...

So I searched around and read that you need to add this to the cURL options/params:

```
CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
```

So I did that:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $json_url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("authorization: Bearer ".$access_token)
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$response_info = curl_getinfo($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

And used this to break up the information:

```
//get response header details
list($headers, $body) = explode("\n\n", $response, 2);
$headers = explode("\n", $headers);
foreach ($headers as $header) {
    list($key, $value) = explode(':', $header, 2);
    $headers[trim($key)] = trim($value);
}
```

And displayed it like so:

```
echo '<p>';
echo "Rate Limit: " . $headers['X-RateLimit-Limit'];
echo " / Remaining Limit: " . $headers['X-RateLimit-Remaining'] . '<br>';
echo "Reset Time: " . $headers['X-RateLimit-Reset'] . '<br>';
echo '</p>';
```

At this point, I -was- getting my needed header response data from Vimeo..

but the rest of the JSON data is now gone/doesnt display anymore.

ie:

```
echo '<h2 class="title">'.$vimeoJSON['name'] . '</h2>';
```

does show up anymore.

If I comment out this line:
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,

This work again.. (however I do NOT get my header response data from Vimeo anymore.

Question is:

- How can I update my code to allow for BOTH??  The header response data from Vimeo.. and still be able to use the $vimeoJSON['xxxx'] data that I have riddled throughout my app?

@Taylor

When using your code sample (I know found on the net elsewhere)

```
//temp
$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($response, $header_size);

echo "HEADER SIZE: " . $header_size . "<br><br>";
echo "HEADER: " . $header . "<br><br>";
echo "BODY: <pre>" . $body . "</pre><br><br>";
```

doesnt matter if I have verbose or header set to true..

the returned embed code is broken?

Seems to come over with double quotes escaped or something:

```
^iframe src=\"https://player.vimeo.com/video/171002772?badge=0&autopause=0&player_id=0\" width=\"900\" height=\"450\" frameborder=\"0\" title=\"How to Save A Dying LVAD - Zachary M. Shinar, MD\" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe^
```

vs

```
^iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/171002772?badge=0&autopause=0&player_id=0" width="900" height="450" frameborder="0" title="How to Save A Dying LVAD - Zachary M. Shinar, MD" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CURLOPT_HEADER` causes the http headers to become part of the output of curl_exec, which means you're not receiving just JSON anymore, you're receiving headers + Json, e.g.

`$response` before:

```
{"foo":"bar"}
```

`$response` after:

```
Header1: value1
header2: value2

{"foo":"bar"}
```

When you pass that `after` value directly to `json_decode()`, it'll barf, because it's **NOT** valid json anymore. You need to rip off the entire header component from that string, so it's just the plain json string again.

Comment: Thanks.. 
This make sense.. but how can I separate them? Is there a built it method?

Comment: by definition, http headers are separated from the body by one blank line. so... split on the blank line, and everything after it should be just the body.

Comment: ahh.. so just manually parse/separate  (duh!)   sorry for being dense there!  I (for whatever reason) was thinking there was some built in CURL/OPT approach to separate.  I'll give it a shot.  (answer accepted)

Maybe put that in your full answer for others (who may have a brain fart as well) to see it!

Comment: yeah, it would be nice if there was a `curl_get_headers()` call to get the headers separately from the body, but .. alas.

Answer (score 1):

`CURLOPT_VERBOSE` comes in handy:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($response, $header_size);
```

Comment: can you elaborate?  comes in handy...how?  (I'm not clear on its use.. nor how its being used in your example to solve my issue?)

Comment: *update:  when I used the example above, specifically the $body var.. when I display the data held in $body.. the iframe/embed code doesnt work? Not sure what effect that has on the datareturned from Vimeo? But the iframe code no longer loads the video/player.  I posted updated code in original post.